# How to multiply a double and add text to label ? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, variables, double

I'm trying to make a windows form with a button that when clicked, multiplies a given input by 5. To do this, I've made a double that called `dblSpeed`. How do I multiply it without changing the variable itself? And how do I then put the answer in a text box? Thanks! Here's the code for the button:

```
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //Declare Variables
        double dblSpeed;

        //Assign user input to double.
        dblSpeed = double.Parse(txtInput.Text);


        //Multiply dblSpeed by 5
        (dblSpeed * 5) ; // Not sure how to put into the output lable. "lblOutput".
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text of a label using the [`Text` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d(v=vs.110).aspx).

`lblOutput.Text = (dblSpeed * 5).ToString();`

This will not change the value of `dblSpeed`, as you are not assigning the value back to the variable.

Comment: That's not going to work without calling `ToString` on the result of the multiplication.

Comment: You're absolutely right, forgot that it doesn't do implicit conversion. Thank you! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtAnswer.Text = (dblSpeed * 5).ToString();
```

Simple like this. ToString() will convert the result into a string value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //Declare Variables
        double dblSpeed;

        //Assign user input to double.
        dblSpeed = Convert.ToDouble(txtInput.Text);


        //Multiply dblSpeed by 5 and put into lable
        lblOutput.Text = (dblSpeed * 5).ToString() ;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the value of the textbox to int and multiply it by 5 after converting it to string and assign it to a label. Like this

```
Int a; 
a = convert.ToInt32(texboxname.text);
Labelname.text = (a*5).ToString();
```